# Android: Can we actually save ImageReader's acquireLatestImage()?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm currently working with the Camera2 API, and created a new `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` object. Of course, it has to implement the `onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)` method. The only thing I want, is to acquire the latest image from this reader, and save it, but unfortunately, I just can't get it. I have read a lot of source codes, visited different StackOverflow topcis, but couldn't find the answer. I'm now at that point, when I have to ask: can this `Image` object actually saved as an image file to the phone's storage? Here is the method:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    buffer.rewind();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes);

    save(bytes);

    image.close();

}
```

The save() method only opens a `FileOutputStream` and writes the bytes to it, it is working. The problem is, I only get a black image, and it has a really small size.

The format of the image is JPEG, this is how I configured my ImageReader instance previously.

I even tryed to convert it to different formats, like from `NV21` to `JPEG` and stuff, but it didn't work out. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class I've used to extract a `Bitmap` from an `Image`.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.media.Image
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import kotlin.experimental.and

class ImagePreprocessor {
    private var rgbFrameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    fun preprocessImage(image: Image?): Bitmap? {
        if (image == null) {
            return null
        }

        check(rgbFrameBitmap!!.width ==  image.width, { "Invalid size width" })
        check(rgbFrameBitmap!!.height == image.height, { "Invalid size height" })

        if (rgbFrameBitmap != null) {
            val bb = image.planes[0].buffer
            rgbFrameBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ByteBufferBackedInputStream(bb))
        }

        return rgbFrameBitmap
    }

    private class ByteBufferBackedInputStream(internal var buf: ByteBuffer) : InputStream() {

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun read(): Int {
            return if (!buf.hasRemaining()) {
                -1
            } else (buf.get() and 0xFF.toByte()).toInt()
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun read(bytes: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int {
            var len = len
            if (!buf.hasRemaining()) {
                return -1
            }

            len = Math.min(len, buf.remaining())
            buf.get(bytes, off, len)
            return len
        }
    }
}
```

I've used this to set the bitmap directly on an `ImageView` but it should be possible to use the `compress` method on the `Bitmap` to save it to file. Note that this only works for JPEG since the data is in a single plane.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample camera2 app, [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)? It [saves JPEGs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L934) with code very similar to yours, and should work fine.

It's possible your other camera setup code has a bug, not the saving part itself. So see if the sample works, and then compare what it does to your code.

Comment: I neither up-vote nor down-vote this answer. Because it works but still is quite useless (a least for me). Because it uses the JPEG format. And the JPEG format slows down the stream significantly.

And unfortunately, the Android team does not seem to provide the better (faster) way of how to do this universally. Or at least, again, I did not find it myself (yet).

The problem is that this is not a main-stream use-case and Android team does not care much about any but main stream (my subjective feeling from the entire Android for past 10 years experience).

Comment: If you want faster capture, request the YUV_420_888 format, which is uncompressed YUV.   It's not as trivial to save as an image file since you'll have to handle the compression/etc yourself, but if you want a burst of data, it's quite fast. Or go all the way to raw Bayer sensor data with RAW_SENSOR format, if you want to.

Comment: Actually, I go completely different direction: Using Camera X + Analyzer: That one seems to be providing the meaningful data (not any low level useless crap, which cannot be easily displayed). Although I still have other problems to handle...